# Wordpress forces HTTPS to HTTP in template

Tags: https

I have a form in a specific page templates with a hidden field and a value of "HTTPS://www.mydomain.com/innerpage".

When I view the source code of the page with the form the value changes to HTTP.
When I strip the inner page, the HTTPS stays.

I need to have this value as HTTPS, so a redirect is not optional.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks!